# Getting the keys out of a Multiindex?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multi-index, levels

I've got a MultiIndex with IDs and Dates, of the form:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[[196003, 196005, 196007, 196009, 196012, 196103, 196105, 196107, 196109, 196112, 196203, 196205, 196207, 196209, 196212, 196303, 196305, 196307, 196309, 196312, 196403, 196405, 196407, 196409, 196412, 201705, 201707, 201709, 201712, 201803, 201805, 201807, 201809, 201812], ['1959-07-01', '1959-07-02', '1959-07-06', '1959-07-07', '1959-07-08', '1959-07-09', '1959-07-10', '1959-07-13', '1959-07-14', '1959-07-15', '1959-07-16', '1959-07-17', '1959-07-20', '1959-07-21', '1959-07-22', '1959-07-23', ...]])
```

Both ID & Date are required to specify a row uniquely.

What I want to do is extract the first level of the index.

When I do `df.index[0]`, I get a tuple of the form `(196003, '1959-07-01')`

What I want is a Series of keys of the form `[196003, 196005, ...]` for level 0.

I managed to get it with:

`list(df[~df['ID'].duplicated()]['ID'].sort_values().reset_index()['ID'])`

but I perceive this to be a messy & slow solution.

What's the pandas-way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can use [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) with [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.unique.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,3],
                   'Dates':['2015-01-01','2015-01-01','2015-02-01'],
                   'C':[7,8,9]})
df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Dates)
df.set_index(['ID', 'Dates'], inplace=True)
print (df)
               C
ID Dates        
1  2015-01-01  7
   2015-01-01  8
3  2015-02-01  9

print (df.index.get_level_values('ID').unique().tolist())
[1, 3]

#another a bit slowier solution
print (df.index.get_level_values('ID').drop_duplicates().tolist())
[1, 3]
```

**Timings**:

```
In [134]: %timeit (orig(df1))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.54 ms per loop

In [138]: %timeit (df.index.get_level_values('ID').unique().tolist())
10000 loops, best of 3: 131 µs per loop

In [139]: %timeit (df.index.get_level_values('ID').drop_duplicates().tolist())
10000 loops, best of 3: 182 µs per loop
```

**Code for timings**:

`len(df) = 3k`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,3],
                   'Dates':['2015-01-01','2015-01-01','2015-02-01'],
                   'C':[7,8,9]})
df = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)
df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Dates)
df.set_index(['ID', 'Dates'], inplace=True)
print (df)


df1 = df.copy()
df1.reset_index('ID', inplace=True)

def orig(df):

    return list(df[~df['ID'].duplicated()]['ID'].sort_values().reset_index()['ID'])

print (df.index.get_level_values('ID').unique().tolist())

print (orig(df1))

print (df.index.get_level_values('ID').drop_duplicates().tolist())
```

Comment: Wow! What a speedup!

Comment: Thanks, this is great!

Comment: Glad can help you!